# Повторный запуск .bat файла после выполнения программы

Tags: python, windows, cmd, bat

Есть файл run.bat, он запускает консольную программу с набором параметров -  program.exe.

Программа выполняется и закрывается (каждый раз в разное время). После, запуск приходится проводить в ручном режиме, то есть запускать опять run.bat.

Вопрос: Подскажите как по средствам Python автоматизировать данный процесс, чтобы run.bat срабатывал после завершения program.exe. Спасибо!

Comment: Хватит обычного батника, стартующего в цикле нужную программу

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста пример кода обычного батника. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
:start
program.exe
goto start
```

У решения есть минус: окно консоли висит в фоне.

P.S. Можно указать полный путь к исполнимому файлу, например:

```
"c:\program files\My prgo\program.exe"
```

Comment: У этого решения один большой минус, оно глупая шутка.. Тем кто это будет пробовать просто положит систему бесконечным перезапуском консоли

Comment: Положит только в том случае, если рабочий процесс будет находиться не в образе вызываемого файла. Т.е. если это будет что-то типо ланчера, который закрывается сразу после вызова, то конечно будет порождаться множество процессов подряд за короткое время. Но в случае, если это стандартный процесс, то батник будет просто "тупо" висеть в фоне ожидая, завершения порожденного процесса. После чего совершит новый вызов. Так-что такой вариант тоже имеет право на жизнь. Впрочем, кому не нравится, могут и сервис вотчдога написать :-)